# How to get Mythtv to use TMDB version 3 api

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

As of today, TMDB dropped support for their version 2.1 api, which is where (mythvideo, at least) is grabbing their data.

How do we set the Ubuntu version of mythtv (0.25) up to use the version 3 api, which is still supported?

I tried replacing tmdb.py with tmdb3.py, and this seems to have helped some, but it seems to crash when more than one possible match is encountered.  Also, I'm not sure if something needs to be done for tvdb searches as well, as I don't currently have any Mythvideo TV shows that are missing metadata.

Any help that could be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you install `tmdb3.py`, and where did you get it from? I saw [this version](http://code.mythtv.org/doxygen/tmdb3_8py_source.html), but haven't tried it yet. I'm trying to solve the same problem myself.

Comment: It do not funcion for me. I have just installed fresh mythbuntu, updated .25 version, dowloaded tmdb3.py copy to tmdb.py - no cooperation between mythbuntu and tmdb3 script
I can run tmdb.py and I receive results but something is wrong with cooperation. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You *can* get it to work:

- Back up /usr/share/mythtv/metadata/Movie/tmdb.py
- Grab the updated version of tmdb3.py from: https://raw.github.com/MythTV/mythtv/983bb0e4353d361f6c54f0de0c0db683b8d3be1d/mythtv/programs/scripts/metadata/Movie/tmdb3.py
- Save it, overwriting /usr/share/mythtv/metadata/Movie/tmdb.py
- Delete ~/.mythtv/pytmdb3.cache to clear out old values

After this, I was able to look up movie information by title and by entering the TMDB number.

Television updates still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

My 12.04 Mythbuntu installation had a tmdb3.py already under /usr/share/mythtv/metadata.  However, it appears to be an earlier version of the script and I don't know if it's accessing V3 of the api.

Using the one from github works for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It would be nice if you would complete your answer adding from where on github you found a new version.